# usage of fxch - assembly code - AT&T syntax

Tags: c, assembly

I'm trying to understand some `assembly code` with `AT&T syntax`.

Here is a snippet:

```
"mov %eax, %ebx; "\
"mov %eax, %ecx;"\
"fxch %st(1);"\
```

This is what I understood from it.

the [`mov`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOV_%28x86_instruction%29) copies (Am I correct?, or does it move?) the data from the `source register` to the `destination register`

In line `one:` we copy the data from registry `eax` to `ebx`.

Similarly, we copy the data from registry `eax` to `ecx`.

However, what I failed to understand is the following. 
How does `fxch` work? Here is a [link](http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH14/CH14-4.html#HEADING4-27) that gives an example.

```
   fxch    st(2)
   fsqrt
   fxch    st(2)
```

It says that this above code takes the `sqrt` of `st(2)`.
Correct me if I am wrong.
It swaps the `top of the stack` with `st(2)` and then takes the `sqrt of what?`
I don't understand that clearly.

Can you please help me out? How does that work in my case and in the above case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mov` instructions indeed copy a value and `fsqrt` takes the square root of the top of the stack and replaces the top of the stack with its result. So the given code sequence effectively takes the square root of `st(2)` and puts it back at the same place.

In answer to your question below. The two `mov` instructions copy the value in register `%eax` to `%ebx` and `%ecx`. So if you add another `mov %eax,%edx`, then this value (from `%eax`) is also copied to `%edx`.

Note that this holds for AT&T assembly. In Intel assembly the values are copied the other way around. In that case `%eax` was, quite uselessly, changed repeatedly to contain the value of the other registers.

The `fxch st(1)` exchanges the top of the stack, which is `st(0)` with the element just below the top `st(1)`. Similarly `st(2)` is just below `st(1)`. Contrary to the integer registers, the floating point registers on the x86 are organized in a stack, reducing the instruction length of operations on those floating point registers as they always work on the top element(s) of the stack. This comes with the overhead of having to use `fxch` instructions to put the right values on the top of the stack.

The integer registers `%eax`, `%ebx` etc. are distinct from the floating point stack/registers `st(0)`, `st(1)` etc. So the `mov` instructions are not related to the `fxch` instructions. The order of these instructions could be changed without effecting the result.

Comment: Thank you. That is clear now. In the first code snippet, what does it do there? if it is followed by another move command like this.
`"mov %eax, %edx;"\`.

Comment: then what role is `fxch st(1)`  playing there?
Edit: Sorry for the confusion.
"mov %eax, %ebx; "\
"mov %eax, %ecx;"\
"fxch %st(1);"\
"mov %eax, %edx"

Comment: Yes. The question has been answered completely. Thanks a lot.